# Writing "Code::Blocks" Without the Colons

Tags: naming, codeblocks

This is a bit of a silly question, but please bear with me.  ;)

I just got the [Code::Blocks](http://codeblocks.org) IDE and I'm enjoying it thoroughly.  However, since the `:` character isn't allowed in Windows folder names, I'm unsure of what to call the folder I keep all my projects in.  (I name each folder after its IDE.)

Should it be written as "Code Blocks," "CodeBlocks," or something else...?

Comment: Not really a good SO question, but to humor: `CodeBlocks` in a case-insensitive FS, `codeblocks` in a case-sensitive FS. I'll leave the reasoning open, but my preference(s) should be pretty clear with that -- I normally *do not* keep my projects in a "per IDE folder". Projects are projects and normally go in one of my "code" directories/repositories. Editors/IDEs just open files/projects. (E.g. why save "MSPaint\Foo.bmp"?)

Comment: The convention in perl (or at least in CPAN) is to use a dash in place of the :: in module names; this may or may not translate well to your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what the people who are affiliated with the project calls it.

- The official name is spelled "Code::Blocks".
- In the filenames in the Download section it's spelled "codeblocks".
- In the page title of the Wiki it's spelled "CodeBlocks"

If you remove the "illegal" characters from the official names you get "CodeBlocks".
However, the :: indicates that they think something should separate "Code" and "Blocks".

According to this, and considering proper grammar, I think you should call it "Code Blocks". Alternatively "Code Blocks IDE".